# semaphore: Not seeing my callback methods invoked, deadlock

Tags: ios, objective-c, grand-central-dispatch, semaphore

I have two light-weight network requests that I'd like to perform concurrently, and then when both are done, invoke a block function.

I've created the method as follows:

```
- (void)loadWithCompletion:(void (^)())completion
{
    dispatch_semaphore_t customerSemaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);
    dispatch_semaphore_t communitySemaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);

    dispatch_async(dispatch_queue_create("mp.session.loader", DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT), ^(void)
    {
        [_customerClient loadCustomerDetailsWithSuccess:^(MPCustomer* customer)
        {
            [self setCurrentCustomer:customer];
            dispatch_semaphore_signal(customerSemaphore);
        } error:^(NSError* error)
        {
            LogDebug(@"Got unexpected error loading customer details: %@", error);
        }];

        [_customerClient loadCommunityDetailsWithSuccess:^(MPCommunity* community)
        {
            [self setCurrentCommunity:community];
            dispatch_semaphore_signal(communitySemaphore);
        } error:^(NSError* error)
        {
            LogDebug(@"Got unexpected error loading customer details: %@", error);
        }];
    });

    dispatch_semaphore_wait(customerSemaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
    dispatch_semaphore_wait(communitySemaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);

    if (completion)
    {
        completion();
    }
}
```

. . it ends up waiting forever. I see my two network requests kick-off, but I never the two callbacks from the two client invocations get invoked, and thus neither semaphore is signaled.

***Why?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wonder if the dispatch queue that you create is being destroyed before it runs the block.  But there is no point in creating a dispatch queue for concurrent operations.  Instead do this:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^(void)...
```

**Update:**

Also, have you checked that your network library is not calling back on the main queue? This will cause a deadlock.

Comment: If you are using async NSURLConnection, then by default this calls back on the main thread, which you are blocking if you are calling the above on the main thread.

Comment: If you block the main thread with your example code then the main thread is blocked.  Any block dispatched on the main thread will not execute.  You should always avoid blocking the main thread.  Just use an async pattern.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I noticed here was that if there is ever an error, you will hang forever, because you signal the semaphores from the "success" blocks but **not** the "failure" blocks. @AndyEtheridge is right about the perils of calling this from the main thread and then waiting for NSURLConnection callbacks that would also be delivered on the same run loop (which you're blocking). That said, this would arguably be better implemented with a more async pattern. Perhaps like this:

```
- (void)loadWithCompletion:(void (^)())completion
{
    dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();
    dispatch_block_t workBlock = ^(void)
    {
        [_customerClient loadCustomerDetailsWithSuccess:^(MPCustomer* customer)
         {
             [self setCurrentCustomer:customer];
             dispatch_group_leave(group);
         } error:^(NSError* error)
         {
             LogDebug(@"Got unexpected error loading customer details: %@", error);
             dispatch_group_leave(group);
         }];

        [_customerClient loadCommunityDetailsWithSuccess:^(MPCommunity* community)
         {
             [self setCurrentCommunity:community];
             dispatch_group_leave(group);
         } error:^(NSError* error)
         {
             LogDebug(@"Got unexpected error loading customer details: %@", error);
             dispatch_group_leave(group);
         }];
    });

    dispatch_queue_t bgQueue = dispatch_queue_create("mp.session.loader", DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT);

    dispatch_group_enter(group); // for the loadCustomer call
    dispatch_group_enter(group); // for the loadCommunity call

    dispatch_async(bgQueue, workBlock);

    dispatch_group_notify(group, [NSThread isMainThread] ? dispatch_get_main_queue() : bgQueue, completion);
}
```

This makes the waiting to call the final completion asynchronous, and specifically calls the completion on the main thread if the initial call to `-loadWithCompletion:` came from the main thread.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I moved the group declaration to the top (as its referenced in the workBlock). . and then gave this approach a try, but it seems to block forever. . . not sure why?

Comment: I like how you decide whether to call back on the main thread.

Comment: The only 2 possibilities I see why this would block forever would be if `_customerClient` is `nil` or if something else is causing the call backs to never be called. Both of those should be relatively easy to check.

Comment: Its definitely neither of those! It's working as expected with the slightly different style of code I posted in my question - after I told BBHTTP (network lib) not to call back on the network queue.

Comment: Frankly, I don't believe you (in that what you're saying implies that `dispatch_group_notify` doesn't work), but if you figured something out that works for you, that's what really matters.

Comment: The fundamental difference between the semaphore approach and the dispatch_group approach is that the semaphore blocks the calling thread until the other operations complete, and the dispatch_group approach does not. That thread could be going on to do any number of things that screw things up that won't happen in the semaphore case. Regardless, I would just set breakpoints in every success/failure callback and in the final completion blocks, and that would tell for sure. If you see 2 calls to dispatch_group_leave happen and *don't* see the final completion get called, I would be very shocked.